# What is the difference (if any) between _mien_ and _demeanor_?

Tags: meaning, differences

*Mien* is a word I don't encounter much, but when I do it always seems like it would have been interchangeable with *demeanor*. Dictionary definitions don't really clarify much (they still seem interchangeable).

Both seem to refer to someone's outward characteristics (look and behaviour) as a reflection of that person's likely or suspected inner characteristics (mood and temperament).

Are they totally interchangeable, or do they have a subtle difference in meaning or usage? Are there any contexts where you might use one, but the other would be inappropriate?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. The two words have the same vague denotation, but they differ in their social stratum. _Mien_ is, as you say, not common, and the reason is that not many know it; it's an academic, sophisticated word and falutes higher than _demeanor_, which itself falutes higher than _manners_ or _behavior_.

Comment: @JohnLawler +1 for *falutes*

Comment: What @verbose said!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mien** and **demeanor** are close, but the latter is somewhat of a subset of the former. **Mien** typically includes a sense of carriage or posture, even a trace of stiffness. One would not say of someone:

> He had the *mien* of a hobo

because hobos aren't typically associated with upright bearing. From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mien):

> Like its synonyms *bearing* and *demeanor*, *mien* means the outward manifestation of personality or attitude. *Bearing* is the most general, but now usually implies characteristic posture, as in "a woman of regal bearing." *Demeanor* suggests attitude expressed through outward behavior in the presence of others; for example, "the manager's professional demeanor." *Mien* is a somewhat literary term referring to both bearing and demeanor. "A mien of supreme self-satisfaction" is a typical use. *Mien* and *demeanor* are also linked through etymology...from Latin *mener* ("to lead").

Here's an example from Toru Dutt's sonnet "[The Lotus](http://www.poetrycat.com/toru-dutt/sonnet--the-lotus)":

> The rose can never tower
>   Like the pale lily with her Juno mien

The connotation is that the lily is taller, more erect, more regal than the rose.